# Error con archivo fxml en JavaFX: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

Tengo el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at userrecognition.Main.start(Main.java:33)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

El error lo marca en las siguiente línea

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("JFXoverlay.fxml"));
```

El archivo Fxml es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="517.0" prefWidth="546.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="userrecognition.FXController">
   <top>
        <VBox>
   <children>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10">
                <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="10" top="10" />
                </padding>
      <children>
                    <CheckBox fx:id="haarClassifier" onAction="#haarSelected" text="Haar Classifier" />
                    <CheckBox fx:id="lbpClassifier" onAction="#lbpSelected" text="LBP Classifier" />
      </children>
            </HBox>
            <Separator />
   </children>
        </VBox>
    </top>
    <center>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER">
            <padding>
                <Insets left="10" right="10" />
            </padding>
   <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="originalFrame" />
   </children>
        </VBox>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER">
            <padding>
                <Insets bottom="25" left="25" right="25" top="25" />
            </padding>
   <children>
            <Button fx:id="cameraButton" alignment="center" disable="true" onAction="#startCamera" text="Start camera" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="newUser" onAction="#newUserSelected" text="New user">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="40.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </CheckBox>
            <TextField fx:id="newUserName" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="130.0" promptText="Enter your name">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="20.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </TextField>
            <Button fx:id="newUserNameSubmit" onAction="#newUserNameSubmitted" text="Submit">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="20.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
   </children>
        </HBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Por si a alguien le sirve,  este error lo resolví dando clean and build en el proyecto, en mi caso utilizaba NetBeans no sé si los demás IDEs también tengan esa opción.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema con JAVAFX + FXML - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/233486/problema-con-javafx-fxml-java-lang-illegalstateexception-location-is-not-se)

Answer (score 0):

Ese error es arrojado porque no encuentra la ruta donde esta el fichero `JFXoverlay.fxml`.

Tienes que revisar bien la ruta

```
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("??????"));
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**.  Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78) y **[pasos para elaborar una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Saludos.