# Problema con JAVAFX + FXML - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

mi problema es el siguiente:

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicacion con FXML pero a la hora de cargar el archivo FXML en JavaFX me esta dando un problema de localizacion de el archivo de FXML, mi estructura de proyecto es la siguiente:

[image: Estructura de proyecto]

Y por aqui os dejo mi clase MainClass.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author verodaht
 */
public class MainClass extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private AnchorPane rootLayout;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");

        initRootLayout();

    }

    private void initRootLayout() throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainClass.class.getResource("/vista/Main.fxml"));

        rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene (rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }



}
```

En la siguiente linea:
**`loader.setLocation(MainClass.class.getResource("/vista/Main.fxml"));`**

El Main.fxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="907.0" prefWidth="1328.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.8114630467571644" prefHeight="907.0" prefWidth="1328.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView prefHeight="905.0" prefWidth="1072.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="181.0" text="NOMBRE" />
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="165.0" text="APELLIDO" />                        <TableColumn prefWidth="232.0" text="POSICION" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="206.0" text="DORSAL" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <VBox fillWidth="false" prefHeight="905.0" prefWidth="246.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="68.0" prefWidth="246.0" text="AÑADIR" AnchorPane.topAnchor="500.0" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="71.0" prefWidth="250.0" text="EDITAR" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="65.0" prefWidth="254.0" text="BORRAR" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

He probado a ponerlo de varias formas ya estilo:

(vista/Main.fxml)
(../vista/Main.fxml)
(/Main.fxml)

Y no se si me dejo alguna.

Y con todas me esta dando el siguiente error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at MainClass.initRootLayout(MainClass.java:33)
    at MainClass.start(MainClass.java:24)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
```

Y no se por que.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Podrias compartir el codigo de tu archivo Main.fxml. ¿Qué controlador tiene asignado?

Comment: hola Ziggy, por aqui te lo dejo

Comment: No veo que tengas asignado un controlador para tu archivo te estaria faltando la declaracion fx:controller="CarpetaControlador.TuControlador" en tu AnchorPane.¿Me explico?, veo tu modelo y vista pero creo que no tenes una clase controlador, es asi? deberias crear un controlador para el Main.fxml

Comment: Prueba de este modo: **`FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/vista/Main.fxml"));`** y nada más.

Comment: Yo probe el codigo que paso y cambiando en el metodo InitiParent.
 rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load(); por rootLayout = loader.load();
 y dejando solo vista/Main.fxml sin la barra (Windows)  funciona, pero creo que los errores que le marca es por el controlador.

Comment: El único problema que estás teniendo es que la llamada a `MainClass.class.getResource("/vista/Main.fxml")` está retornando `null`, por eso cuando llamas al `load()` obtienes `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set`. Asegúrate de que tu IDE esté construyendo correctamente tu proyecto y depositando en el directorio de salida (donde mete los .class) el archivo FXML.

Comment: alfinal lo conseguiste arreglar? es que tengo el mismo error

Comment: @IgnacioBelmonte reinicie el IDE y funciono todo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes aplicar estos algoritmos para cargar el FXML

```
public Parent cargarFXML(String rutaFXML) {

    Parent root = null;
    try {
       root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(rutaFXML));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(VentanaImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return root;
```

Luego puedes cargar cualquier ventana

```
public void nuevaVentana(String rutaFXML) {
   Stage stage = new Stage();
   //stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);


   Scene scene = new Scene(this.cargarFXML(rutaFXML));
  // scene.setFill(null);

   stage.setTitle("Sistema de Gestión de Documentos");
   stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResource("/proyectogestiondocumental/recursos/logo.png").toExternalForm()));


   stage.setScene(scene);
   //stage.setResizable(false);
   stage.sizeToScene();
   stage.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es porque no tienes controlador. Si pulsas en el archivo .fxml botón derecho, deberías de tener la opción de make controller como te pongo en la imagen
[image: make controller]

Sino dentro del xml, le tienes que agregar al anchorpane principal la siguiente etiqueta y crear tu el archivo del controlador a mano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura es fx:controller="NombrePaquete.NombreDelControlador+Controller"

El resultado en el árbol sería el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola compañero buenas tardes, hace poco se me presento el mismo problema y la solucion fue indicar de manera directa el archivo .fxml apesar que este se encuentre dentro de otro paquete ademas sin /