# javafx: Location is required

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Esta es la falla el ejecutar el programa ya reinicie el NetBeans pero aun así la falla continua

Por que me sale el siguiente error en mi programa de javafx con fxml?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Los errores, como texto.. y como podemos saber que causa el error sin ver el programa???

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema con JAVAFX + FXML - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/233486/problema-con-javafx-fxml-java-lang-illegalstateexception-location-is-not-se)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la ruta de donde se encuentra tu archivo FXML no lo encuetra el IDE para ejecutarlo.
La manera mas simple para desplegar tu aplicacion seria algo asi..

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("inicio.fxml")); // aca debes colocar la ruta completa de donde se encuentra tu archivo fxml
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
    stage.setTitle("Saludos!");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
```